# How to use URL as virtual path in IIS Express

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, iis-express

When developing a web app, I'd rather not pull down all of the images and videos to my repository or my working drive.  I only want my code.  The code uses relative paths to the images, such as src="/NAS/images/blah.jpg".  I tried using this...

```
<virtualDirectory path="/NAS/" physicalPath="http://www.example.com/NAS/" />
```

in the applicationhost.config but Visual Studio throws a fit.  Is there anyway to do this short of mapping a local drive letter to that NAS folder?

Comment: Don't invent anything. IIS requires "physicalPath" to be a real physical path, not URL, which is by design.

Comment: So what is the typical thing to do, keep a copy of the images, etc. in your working directory or ???  My thought would be to use a global setting, variable that could check for localhost and include, or not, the full URL path.

Comment: link to the images directly in your web pages. You don't need the virtual directory at all.